# running asyncio with streamlit dashboard

Tags: python-asyncio, streamlit

How do I create a [streamlit dashboard](https://docs.streamlit.io/) that doesn't continuously append the new values from the `asyncio.gather(firstWorker(),secondWorker()`? The code below runs but will very quickly turn into a very long dashboard where I was hoping to figure out if I could just 2 ***fixed*** streamlit `title or metric` to represent workerOne workerTwo where only the `val_one` and `val_two` are updated on the dashboard. streamlit [metric](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.metric) or [text](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text) elements seem to all have the same behavior of continuously appending...any tips appreciated.

Am using python 3.10 on Windows 10 running the dashboard with: `$ streamlit run app.py`

```
import streamlit as st
import asyncio
import random as r

val_one = 0
val_two = 0


st.title("Hello World")

async def firstWorker():
    global val_one
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
        val_one = r.randint(1, 10)
        st.metric("First Worker Executed: ",val_one)


async def secondWorker():
    global val_two
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
        val_two = r.randint(1, 10)
        st.metric("Second Worker Executed: ",val_two)


async def main():
    await(asyncio.gather(
        firstWorker(), 
        secondWorker()
            )
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
```

Trying to avoid if possible an infinite long dashboard as well as have the anyscio processes run in the background even if the streamlit dashboard isnt being utilized by a web browser.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the code after `if __name__ == '__main__':` into `st.empty()` container to overwrite the previous content whenever an update is made.

```py
import streamlit as st
import asyncio
import random as r

val_one = 0
val_two = 0


st.title("Hello World")
async def firstWorker():
    global val_one
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
        val_one = r.randint(1, 10)
        st.metric("First Worker Executed: ",val_one)


async def secondWorker():
    global val_two
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
        val_two = r.randint(1, 10)
        st.metric("Second Worker Executed: ",val_two)


async def main():
    await(asyncio.gather(
        firstWorker(),
        secondWorker()
            )
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with st.empty(): # Modified to use empty container
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        try:
            asyncio.run(main())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            print("Closing Loop")
            loop.close()
```

Output:

[image]

**Version 2:**

```py
st.title("Hello World")

async def firstWorker():
    await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
    val_one = r.randint(1, 10)
    st.metric("First Worker Executed: ", val_one)


async def secondWorker():
    await asyncio.sleep(r.randint(1, 3))
    val_two = r.randint(1, 10)
    st.metric("Second Worker Executed: ", val_two)


async def main():
    with st.empty():
        while True:
            left_col, right_col = st.columns(2)
            with left_col:
                await (asyncio.gather(firstWorker()))
            with right_col:
                await (asyncio.gather(secondWorker()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I don't know why you use `global` variables. I got rid of them this time unless otherwise you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sort of curious can your answer be modified to represent two empty containers? `with st.empty()` To show worker one and two at the same time?

Comment: Sure you can do that if you want, with the use of `st.columns()` that will enable you to display the content in two separate columns. But before achieving that goal, you will have to refactor the entire code otherwise the `While True:` loops in the separate functions will make the code behave just like the answer I provided before. I will edit the answer to and the refactored version of the code at the bottom of the existing answer so you can try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much....another thing I notice is if I run the app and close out of the web browser the asncyio functions/calculations also stop as well....would you know if its possible if I close the browser that the entire app/asnycio would keep running? I guess sort of like Flask app I think would keep crunching numbers in the background whether or not I was dialed into the dashboard, hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: You are welcome @bbartling. Calculations should continue running once the app is not stopped from the terminal. You can observe the figures, close the browser and open it again. The figure will for sure change. The browser is just there to tell us what the code is doing.

Comment: In the second example corutines don't run in parallel (you wait for the first corutine, then for the second corutine, and so on). Instead, you need to create a list of task, in `while True` loop wait them with `await asyncio.wait(workers, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)`, then check which worker is finished, show its result and then create new task for this worker.